# Baseboard heater - bleeder valve and?

Tags: valve, heater, baseboard, air

A plumber installed the following - see picture. I have no plumbing knowledge, but I believe the bigger piece (on the left) is an air "bleeding" valve but what is that red pull valve on the right for? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shutoff valve, of the 1/4 turn ball type. It's presently open.

The thing to the right of the shutoff valve might be a balancing valve, used to adjust water flow relative to other heating loops to "balance" heat delivery.

Comment: Do you think the thing to the right of the red shutoff valve (I assume you are referring to the small round screw looking thing) was there prior to the installation of the bleeder and shutoff? Like is there a way to tell based on the colors of the connections)? Sorry for not using proper words.

Comment: It appears likely that it was there before the new work, from the color of things, yes.